# How do you embed an object within current context in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js script file. I am requiring a class with static functions. I would like to embed the class right into current context of script so I can just call the function names of the class without referring to the class name.

In class file:

```
class SomeClass {
     static doIt() {...}
}
```

In script file:

```
let cls = require('SomeClass');

// **** embed class into current context here ***

// Just call the function without class reference
doIt();
```

I have seen this done before. Cannot find online how to do this.

Comment: `var doIt = cls.doIt`. If you want to do this dynamically in module scope you need `eval`. `with` might work if you are not in strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring to do that:

```
class SomeClass {
     static doIt() {...}
     static otherFunc() {...}
}

const { doIt, otherFunc } = SomeClass;

doIt();
```

Comment: Actually now I remember this was possible in PHP without any extra declarations. The answers provided are good enough. I will just use one of those methods.